# Showing all attachments in Issue list

Tags: view, attachments, issue-tracking

I have to create a repository or just a view that will contain/show all attachments of an Issue list.

Please guide me how can I do that.
Should I do it declaratively or I should do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You have two scenarios:

1. Create view where show at only items with attachments.

   - Plus: fast implement without code programmatically.
   - Minus: You can only see the elements and not the files that are attachments. To see what attachments you have of inputs on each element separately.
2. Create a webpart with view all attachments list (you can use a sandbox webpart). Using the object SPQury and CAML select all elements that have attachments. Then for each of the element obtained save the addresses of all its attachments. At the end of the resulting list display to the user.

   - Plus: You only see attachments and you have direct access to them.
   - Minus: The longer the time to obtain a solution. You must program the webpart from the base. You must create a mechanism for collecting and displaying data to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this method but you can try:-

Create a new view.

Then, edit this view and add the attachment column. In the properties of this column, there may be an option to filter for attachments 'equals' Yes.